# how to get the password from the database?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

please help to get the user's password by username

views.py:

```
def qwe(request):
    if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax():
        #username = request.POST.get('username', '')        
        username ="admin"

        username_req = User.objects.filter(username=username)               

        if username_req.exists():
            pass = username_req[0].password

    return HttpResponse(pass)
```

error message in log is:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: explain this .! why you need pswd ?

Comment: And if you plan to implement pswd reset functionality see this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/_modules/django/contrib/auth/forms/#PasswordResetForm

Comment: hmmm, apart of the good answer of Hasan Ramezani, the error is not about the password but only because you do a queryset filter that is empty. The resulting list is empty and you try to access the item at the index 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to security restrictions it is impossible to get user password.

Comment: but https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.check_password

Comment: `check_password` making a hash from your string and compare with hash stored in database

Comment: this is for check password, not get password.

Answer (score 0):

You will get a hash, not a plaintext password.

And you are using system-reserved keyword `pass`.
One more thing - if user will not found, your variable will be not defined and exception will be raised.